# i want to change css vars of extjs

Tags: css, extjs

I want to set back-ground color of panel using $panel-body-background-color. then
how can I set in panel config ? I am getting error in following peace of code.

here is code

```
var mainPanel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
  renderTo: Ext.get('main'),
  xtype: 'form',
  title: 'User Registration',
  $panel-body-background-color : black /style:{'$panel-body-background-color:#64FE2E'}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$panel-body-background-color are not component configurations, they are SASS variables. They are defined and configured outside of you app code. See the link below for a quick tutorial on ExtJS theming. Its very powerful but can be overwhelming at first.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/theming

You should be using Sencha Command to make this work properly, if you are you can explore the packages folder to see the themes and how they are set up. You can also use Sencha Command to create a new theme:

```
sencha generate theme my-custom-theme
```

Answer (score 0):

May I know the reason of changing the background color ?

The code can look like this,

```
  Ext.onReady(function() {
    var mainPanel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
               renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
               title: 'User Registration',
               width:300,
               height:400,
               bodyStyle:{
                 background:'pink'
               }
    });
  });
```

Comment: i want to change header color of panel. how can i do?